# Not having to extend and section in every file Laravel/Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is it possible to make every view extend my main layout without having to put @extends('layout') and @section('content') in every file at the top? For example by using a provider? I'm new to Laravel and Blade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its better to use extend but in case you want to get rid of @extends or @section, you can always return your main layout from controller and pass views as parameters to the main layout.

mainlayout.blade.php:

```php
//replace yield directive with content variable
//            @yield('content')
{!!$content!!}
```

in controller:

```php
//return view('test');

$content=view('test')->render();
return view('mainlayout',['content'=>$content]);
```

Now in test view you don't need @extends and @section.